# How to iterate over a list of Marker in Java?

Tags: java, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, processing

```
List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<Marker>();
 List<PointFeature> earthquakes = ParseFeed.parseEarthquake(this, earthquakesURL);



  for( PointFeature earthquake: earthquakes){



    SimplePointMarker marker = new SimplePointMarker(earthquake.getLocation());
    map.addMarker(marker); // <---- I used this method from Unfolding Maps library, 
                         //does this method add elements to the array list?

    }

...  // Code
...


for(Marker markerz : markers){
        System.out.println("Hello");
    Object magn=markerz.getProperty("magnitude");

    float magnitude= Float.parseFloat(magn.toString());
    System.out.println(magnitude);

    if( magnitude<=4.0){
        markerz.setColor(color(0, 0, 255));

    }
    else  if((float) magnitude<=4.9){
        markerz.setColor(color(255, 255 , 0 ));

    }
    else  if((float) magnitude>=5.0){
        markerz.setColor(color(255, 0 , 0 ));}

    else{
            markerz.setColor(color(150,150,150));
        }

    }
```

I am doing this online course where they are asking me to make markers on a map and then change the markers color according to the magnitude of the earthquake. I am trying to iterate over **markers** which is an arrayList I thought there must be some problem with the my conditional statements. Then I attached a print line statement in the loop to check whether the control is going inside the loop. But the "Hello" is also not being printed. How to iterate over the loop? I have another ArrayList which is of type Point feature. Can I iterate over this?

Comment: Just prior to the for loop you should add a log line printing the size of the `markers` list. Maybe it's just an empty list :)

Comment: markers is an empty arraylist unless you are doing something to fill it with in the "Code" so it's normal that even the "Hello" is not printed

Answer (score 2):

```
for(Marker markerz : markers)
```

is a good way to iterate a List. But your List object "markers" on which you iterate is probably empty so the loop will not execute. Make sure to add some Marker objects to it in the //Code part.

Answer (score -1):

```
for (PointFeature earthquake : earthquakes) {
               SimplePointMarker earthquakeMarker = createMarker(earthquake);
               markers.add(earthquakeMarker);//this adds to the list <marker>
         }
           map.addMarkers(markers); // this adds to the markers to the map
```

// below is the createMarker()

```
private SimplePointMarker createMarker(PointFeature feature)
    {
        int yellow = color(255, 255, 0); // using PApplet to get int from RGB to put into Marker
        int blue = color(0, 0, 255);
        int red = color(255, 0, 0);
        float earthquakeRadius = 0; //initialize radius
        int earthquakecolor = 0; //initialize color
        Object magObj = feature.getProperty("magnitude");
        float mag = Float.parseFloat(magObj.toString()); // get magnitude from earthquake object

        if (mag < 4.0) {earthquakeRadius = 8; earthquakecolor = blue;}
        else if (mag <5.0) {earthquakeRadius = 15; earthquakecolor = yellow;}
        else {earthquakeRadius = 25; earthquakecolor = red;}

        Location earthquakeLocation = feature.getLocation(); // get locations
        SimplePointMarker earthquakeMarker = new SimplePointMarker(earthquakeLocation);
        earthquakeMarker.setRadius(earthquakeRadius); // sets radius
        earthquakeMarker.setColor(earthquakecolor);
        return earthquakeMarker;
        // finish implementing and use this method, if it helps.
        //return new SimplePointMarker(feature.getLocation());
    }
```